# Yii2: Return to previous page with id number Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Hey I have two tables company and tour. A company can have more than one tour. I can list them all. When I click for update and decide to not to update( cancel update button) I want to go back to the company/view.php file which includes all other tours that company has…

This is my updatecontroller.

```
 public function actionUpdate($id) {
$company= ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->all(),'id','name');
$model = CompanyPerson::findOne($id);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
{
    $model->save();
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', ' updated');
    return $this->redirect(Url::to(['company/view', 'id' => $id]));
}

return $this->render('update',[
    'model' => $model,
    'company' => $company

]);
```

in the update.php view file

```
<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['company/view', 'id'=> $model -> id]); ?>" class="btn btn-app">
        <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel
    </a>
```

The cancel button assign the the company-person id number to the company_id. Since there is no record in that company_id number, It wont display any thing. hope I explained well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you have a `$model->company_id` attribute that you can use?

Comment: Actually, in my updatecontroller, I defined the $company variable. I  uppose Ican get the id there. So I did this way but it says : "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: The `variable` does not hold the company related to this model, you are assigning it to an array of all possible companies "id" => "name". Not sure how you are using this.

Comment: In any case, it seems like it makes sense to have a `$companyPerson->company` relation defined, this would be the cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Can you add your `Company` and `CompanyPerson` active record code to the question?

Comment: I figured out Thanks. As you said I used the  $company->id relation like so:  <a href="<?php echo Url::to(['company/view', 'id'=> $model->company->id]); ?>" class="btn btn-app">
            <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Sil
        </a>

Comment: Call only the field that relates to Company model... don't call whole object if you don't use the information :) unnecessary information and database query